# Not completed file reading

Tags: file-io, lua

I'm trying to print the number of rows in my file `training.txt` but found out that my code does not read the whole file. Code goes like this:

```
row = 1
for line in io.lines 'training.txt' do
    row = row + 1
end
print(row)
```

I tried changing the file with `test.txt` that has the same format with `training.txt` and file reading worked fine, reads until the end of file. So maybe the problem is with my text file? But how? It has the same format.

Text files are uploaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/jxccebt0v3jfb/files) for testing.

Comment: You should start with `row=0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file you uploaded `training.txt` is not the same format as `test.txt`, it does not have newline characters that indicate the EOL (End of Line). Try opening it in notepad to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! Was opening it in a different program that's why i didnt see the difference.